# How to present set of point in mathematical way

Tags: notation

I have a question about presenting the set of point in the math. I have two sets in domain $\Omega$. $M$ is set of $m$ point locations, $N$ is set of $n$ point locations. In which,some points in the set $M$ have same location with set $N$. I want to represent some condition in mathematical way. Could you help me represent it?

1. Represent set $M,N$
2. Represent the intersection between $M$ and $N$
3. Represent points $\in M$ but not belong $N$

Thank you in advance.

These are my results. But I am not sure about my answers.

1. Represent set $M,N$
   $$M=\{(x_i,y_i) \mid i=1,\dots,m,(x_i,y_i) \in \Omega \}$$
   (Or only $M=\{(x,y) \mid (x,y) \in \Omega \}$???)
   $$N=\{(x_j,y_j) \mid j=1,\dots,n, (x_n,y_n) \in \Omega \}$$
2. Represent the intersection between $M$ and $N$
   $$K=M\bigcap N=\{(x_k,y_k) \mid (x_k,y_k) \in \Omega, (x_k,y_k) \in M \text{ and } (x_k,y_k) \in N \}$$
3. Represent points $\in M$ but not belong $N$
   $$H=\{(x_h,y_h) \mid (x_h,y_h) \in \Omega, (x_h,y_h) \in M \text{ and } (x_h,y_h) \notin N \}$$

Comment: Representation theory is something else. Wrong tag.

Comment: Is the domain $\Omega$ a subset of $\Bbb{C}$ or $\Bbb{R}^2$?  If so, then you should say so.  It seems like you want to describe the points in $\Omega$ as ordered pairs, so I can *guess* that $\Omega \subseteq \Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I don't really know what you could say, other than $M$ is larger than $N$ if $m \geq n$.

Comment: @SammyBlack: Yes. It \in $R^2$. For example, it is image domain. William Stagner: Because I don't know the relationship between $m$ and $n$. So I write "we don't know which is bigger". Sometime, m is bigger than n.But sometime m is smaller than n

Comment: Then it's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: I must represent condition 1 to 3 by mathematic. That is my question

Comment: @  William Stagner: I updated my question. I deleted the sentence $m>n$